# Calendar will not render on iPad 2nd Generation

Tags: fullcalendar

FullCalendar works great on Chrome on my PC but it does not render on an iPad 2nd generation.  Is there maybe some polyfil code needed?

Answer (score 1):

Linking to a polyfill script fixed this issue for me!  Found the solution [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4558)

Edit: This was the actual line that fixed it...

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
```